# How to add custom dropdown menu in react-draft-wysiwyg?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wysiwyg, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I need to add custom dropdown menu in toolbar section.

here attached image similar to want dropdown menu this is possible ?

```
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/OhYeFsL.png" alt="Dropdown menu editor">
```

find the detailed image below

[image]

I used react-draft-wysiwyg content editor.

https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg

https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/d

add custom dropdown menu in toolbar section.

Answer (score 18):

I hope this is still relevant, but here is my way.

For the custom dropdown, I created a new component and used method for "adding new option to the toolbar" from the documentation https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/docs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { EditorState, Modifier } from 'draft-js';

class Placeholders extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    editorState: PropTypes.object,
  }

  state = {
    open: false
  }

  openPlaceholderDropdown = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open})

  addPlaceholder = (placeholder) => {
    const { editorState, onChange } = this.props;
    const contentState = Modifier.replaceText(
    editorState.getCurrentContent(),
    editorState.getSelection(),
    placeholder,
    editorState.getCurrentInlineStyle(),
    );
    onChange(EditorState.push(editorState, contentState, 'insert-characters'));
  }

  placeholderOptions = [
    {key: "firstName", value: "{{firstName}}", text: "First Name"},
    {key: "lastName", value: "{{lastName}}", text: "Last name"},
    {key: "company", value: "{{company}}", text: "Company"},
    {key: "address", value: "{{address}}", text: "Address"},
    {key: "zip", value: "{{zip}}", text: "Zip"},
    {key: "city", value: "{{city}}", text: "City"}
  ]

  listItem = this.placeholderOptions.map(item => (
    <li 
      onClick={this.addPlaceholder.bind(this, item.value)} 
      key={item.key}
      className="rdw-dropdownoption-default placeholder-li"
    >{item.text}</li>
  ))

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.openPlaceholderDropdown} className="rdw-block-wrapper" aria-label="rdw-block-control">
        <div className="rdw-dropdown-wrapper rdw-block-dropdown" aria-label="rdw-dropdown">
          <div className="rdw-dropdown-selectedtext" title="Placeholders">
            <span>Placeholder</span> 
            <div className={`rdw-dropdown-caretto${this.state.open? "close": "open"}`}></div>
          </div>
          <ul className={`rdw-dropdown-optionwrapper ${this.state.open? "": "placeholder-ul"}`}>
            {this.listItem}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Placeholders;
```

I used a custom dropdown for adding placeholders. But the essence still stays the same because I use the example from the documentation for a custom button.

To render the button itself I used the same styling, classes, and structure as is used for the other dropdown buttons. I just switched the anchor tag to div tag and added custom classes for hover style and carrot change. I also used events to toggle classes.

```
  .placeholder-ul{
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .placeholder-li:hover {
    background: #F1F1F1;
  }
```

Lastly, don't forget to import and add a custom button to the editor.

```
<Editor
   editorState={this.state.editorState}
   onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
   toolbarCustomButtons={[<Placeholders />]}
/>
```

Comment: Maybe you could suggest, how could one use modalHandler to close the dropdown if user clicks away? https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/docs 

I've tried by using the example there but I can't solve the issue where dropdown gets opened if user clicks anywhere (the closing part works as expected).

Comment: Hi  @Tomas, Can I render html using custom toolbar button?

Answer (score 1):

I'v used Tomas his code and updated it a bit to TypeScript / Function components.
Can concur that this solution is still working in 2020 with Draft.js v0.10.5

```js
type ReplacementsProps = {
  onChange?: (editorState: EditorState) => void,
  editorState: EditorState,
}


export const Replacements = ({onChange, editorState}: ReplacementsProps) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const addPlaceholder = (placeholder: string): void => {
    const contentState = Modifier.replaceText(
      editorState.getCurrentContent(),
      editorState.getSelection(),
      placeholder,
      editorState.getCurrentInlineStyle(),
    );
    const result = EditorState.push(editorState, contentState, 'insert-characters');
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(result);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={() => setOpen(!open)} className="rdw-block-wrapper" aria-label="rdw-block-control" role="button" tabIndex={0}>
      <div className="rdw-dropdown-wrapper rdw-block-dropdown" aria-label="rdw-dropdown" style={{width: 180}}>
        <div className="rdw-dropdown-selectedtext">
          <span>YOuR TITLE HERE</span>
          <div className={`rdw-dropdown-caretto${open ? 'close' : 'open'}`} />
        </div>
        <ul className={`rdw-dropdown-optionwrapper ${open ? '' : 'placeholder-ul'}`}>
          {placeholderOptions.map(item => (
            <li
              onClick={() => addPlaceholder(item.value)}
              key={item.value}
              className="rdw-dropdownoption-default placeholder-li"
            >
              {item.text}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer was too long for a comment.

Tomas's answer is correct. This is an addendum to answer Tadej's question/comment.

In your Placeholder component, set a ref on your outermost div.

Here is how you would handle it according to the functional component paradigm in React:

```js
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

const openPlaceholder = () => setOpen(!open);

useEffect(() => {
    const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
      if (smart.current && !smart.current.contains(event.target)) {
        setOpen(false);
      }
    };
      
    document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);
      
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, []);
    
    
return (
  <div ref={smart} onClick={() => openPlaceholder()} className="rdw-block-wrapper" aria-label="rdw-block-control">

   // ... the rest of the dropdown.

  </div>
);
```